# Sorting an array by entry properties, with optional grouping

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {"timestamp" => 1347119549, "category" => nil},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119547, "category" => "Monkeys"},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119543, "category" => nil},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119542, "category" => "Monkeys"}
]
```

I want to sort it by timestamp (descending), UNLESS it has a category not being nil, in which case it should appear with it's "siblings", even though it is "older" than an uncategorized entry. I need to sort this array, so it appears like this:

```
[
    {"timestamp" => 1347119549, "category" => nil},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119547, "category" => "Monkeys"},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119542, "category" => "Monkeys"},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119543, "category" => nil}
]
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the correct result by using `group_by` and `sort`, but have had no success.

Comment: *Should appear by it's siblings* But where in the order? Suppose you have 3 entries with the category "Monkeys", where in the sorted list do they appear? By the first "Monkey" entry? Second? Third? None of the above?

Comment: Good question, sorry I didn't clarify that. They should appear by the first entry, effectively inserting them, pushing the following entries "down" :)

Comment: @Borodin's solution is the simplest and best performing.  It's roughly twice as fast as the chosen answer: https://gist.github.com/dresselm/6099437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply done using the tools you've tried.

First `sort` the entire array by tiemstamp, and then allocate them groups by category using `group_by`:

```
arr = [
    {'timestamp' => 1347119549, 'category' => nil},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119547, 'category' => 'Monkeys'},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119543, 'category' => nil},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119542, 'category' => 'Monkeys'},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119541, 'category' => nil},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119548, 'category' => nil},
    {'timestamp' => 1347119545, 'category' => nil},
]

sorted = arr.sort_by { |elem| 0 - elem['timestamp'] }
groups = sorted.group_by { |elem| elem['category'] or Object.new }
sorted = groups.values.flatten

puts sorted
```

**output**

```
{"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil}
{"timestamp"=>1347119548, "category"=>nil}
{"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"}
{"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"}
{"timestamp"=>1347119545, "category"=>nil}
{"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}
{"timestamp"=>1347119541, "category"=>nil}
```

You could, of course, pipeline the whole thing, at the cost of readability.

```
sorted = arr.sort_by { |elem| 0 - elem['timestamp'] }.group_by { |elem| elem['category'] or Object.new }.values.flatten
```

Comment: It is not the output expected as said by OP.. :)

Comment: At first, I thought that was what OP wanted, but it does not match the OP's expected output. I still do not understand what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Ah I see. The timestamp sort order needs to be backwards, and groups of hashes with a non-nil `category` are sorted by their latest timestamp. Fixed.

Comment: I feel like your final solution is definitely the best.  It's simple and efficient. I suggest you update your answer to describe why you are using `0` in the `sort_by`, highlight the `or Object.new` trick and highlight the use of `values` vs the other solutions using `map`.

Comment: I completely agree, this is the best solution.

In regards to the purpose, the initial code didn't reveal it, as I wanted to simplify it instead of just pasting the real "production" code. it's actually for handling categorization of images. I want to display a sequence of imagesets based on time. However, some imagesets are grouped together, and as such should be shown together, as they have traits in common. So chronological with a twist :)

Thanks everyone for the quick responses, it was actually quite overwhelming :)

Comment: @JesperRasmussen: It's more to do with your question being an interesting one than than the goodness of our hearts :)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pp'

ar = [
    {"timestamp" => 1347119549, "category" => nil},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119547, "category" => "Monkeys"},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119543, "category" => nil},
    {"timestamp" => 1347119542, "category" => "Monkeys"}
]

pp ar.group_by{|h| h['category'] ? h['category'] : h['timestamp']}.
   map{|k,v| v.sort_by{|h| -h['timestamp']}}.
   sort_by{|a| -a[0]['timestamp']}.flatten
# >> [{"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}]
```

---

```
require 'pp'

a = [
  {"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119548, "category"=>"Dog"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119544, "category"=>"Dog"}
]

pp a.group_by{|h| h['category'] ? h['category'] : h['timestamp']}.
   map{|k,v| v.sort_by{|h| -h['timestamp']}}.
   sort_by{|a| -a[0]['timestamp']}.flatten 
# >> [{"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119548, "category"=>"Dog"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119544, "category"=>"Dog"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
# >>  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}]
```

Comment: @tessi I took your example array too, just to test my solution,if it works perfectly or not.. :))

Comment: Hehe, seems to work :) Btw: Just did a minor edit to your code, so that it can be copy-pasted into an IRB without syntax errors.

Comment: @tessi Its OK.. That I understood... :)

Comment: I didn't think of using `"timestamp"` as the alternative value to prevent the `nil` items grouping. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a little ugly, but it works:

```
a = [
  {"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119548, "category"=>"Dog"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119544, "category"=>"Dog"}
]
groups = a.sort_by {|h| -h['timestamp']}.group_by {|h| h['category']}
sorted = (groups.delete(nil) || []) + groups.values
sorted = sorted.sort_by{|i| i.is_a?(Hash) ? -i['timestamp'] : -i.first['timestamp']}.flatten
```

This gives you the following in `sorted`:

```
[
  {"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119548, "category"=>"Dog"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119544, "category"=>"Dog"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"},
  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}
]
```

I sort first by `'timestamp'`, so that the groups are sorted later.

After grouping by `'category'`, I move the values of the `nil` category in an array. Here, I use `(groups.delete(nil) || [])` in case the `nil` group is empty.

Now it can be sorted by `'timestamp'` again, with the `timestamp` of an array being the `timestamp` of its first hash.

Finally `flatten` gives us the desired array.

Comment: Well, I was kind of expecting the solution to not be pretty :) It's not really a simple problem, based on the fact that timestamp is the primary order unless a category is set.

Answer (score 1):

The trick required here is to assign a *unique* group instead of nil. You can do that simply by creating a generic Ruby `Object`.

```
orig = [
  {"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil}, 
  {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"}, 
  {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}, 
  {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"}]

# The "tricky bit"
grouped = orig.group_by { |x| x["category"] ?  x["category"] : Object.new  }

# Sort the siblings within the groups (note negation causes reverse order)
grouped.values.each { |siblings| siblings.sort_by! { |a| -a["timestamp"] } }

# Sort the list by first (i.e. "best" sort order) timestamp in each group 
sorted_groups = grouped.sort_by { |group_id,siblings| -siblings.first["timestamp"] }

# Remove group ids and flatten the list:
result = sorted_groups.map { |group_id,siblings| siblings }.flatten
=>  [
 {"timestamp"=>1347119549, "category"=>nil}, 
 {"timestamp"=>1347119547, "category"=>"Monkeys"}, 
 {"timestamp"=>1347119542, "category"=>"Monkeys"}, 
 {"timestamp"=>1347119543, "category"=>nil}
]
```

Comment: sounds interesting :) however the timestamp should be reverse-sorted

Comment: @tessi: I cannot see where that is specified, but yes does seem to match the example. Thanks, I will fix it . . .

Comment: Just got it from the example, you are right, it is not specified in his description :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I didn't specify that more precisely :)

Comment: @tessi: Yes, I managed to break it when trying to reverse order. Got it now , thanks!

Comment: I like how you reverse using `-`. I copy that bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: Nice how you use `Object.new` to get a unique identifier so each `nil` gets its own group. Very concise. I think I would have used an incrementing counter instead. I Also like the logic of the steps you take. As the others have done, using the `timestamp` as group-id would also work, if two items have nil category and the same timestamp, it would still produce the correct result.

Comment: Using `Object.new` is also a good option if the sort order is something more complex than simply another property. Although you could also define a method which figures out what the sort property is, and use that as a default group as well as sort.

Comment: Looks like I've ended up with pretty much the same thing. Note that `x["category"] ?  x["category"] : Object.new` is the same as `x["category"] || Object.new`.